# Adding Info Page to mapkit app

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have made a map App that when opened first shows the MapView and has various annotations.

I am now looking at trying to add a info page (a little "i" button like with the map annotations) in the corner of the MapView to segue to another view having a brief explanation of the app.

How would I go about doing this? 
I have tried putting a button directly on top of the MapView but it just seems to delete the MapView and center the button. Is this due to my Segue from the MapView annotations info buttons to their respective info pages?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried and this wasn't the case for me. You must check that you are properly placing that button above Mapview and the segue is connected from button or not?

Comment: How do I make sure I am placing it above the MapView?

Comment: I don't have a UIView behind the MapView. Would that cause this to happen?

Comment: You can check in Size Inspector for the container . And well i have a Uiview behind the MapView.

Comment: I checked in the connections inspector and when I place the button it removes the MapView and shows no Segue for the button.

Comment: please add screenshot for the same.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the connections inspector? I have just attached a UI View underneath and now the button is appearing above. I will check if a segue can be performed

Comment: sorry for the confusion i am using GMSMapViewDelegate not MapKit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
let baseURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

var lookupAddressResults: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var fetchedFormattedAddress: String!

var fetchedAddressLongitude: Double!

var fetchedAddressLatitude: Double!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//Setup our Location Manager


let address = storeAddress.text

    self.geocodeAddress(address, withCompletionHandler: { (status, success) -> Void in
        if !success {
            print(status)

            if status == "ZERO_RESULTS" {
                print("location not found")
            }
        }
        else {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.fetchedAddressLatitude, longitude: self.fetchedAddressLongitude)
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)



            //self.mapview.camera = camera
            //self.mapview.animateToCameraPosition(camera)
            //let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            self.mapView.camera = camera
            self.mapView.animateToZoom(18)
            self.mapView.setMinZoom(15, maxZoom: 25)
            self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain;
            self.mapView.delegate=self;
            let marker = GMSMarker()




            marker.position = camera.target
            marker.snippet = address
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            marker.map = self.mapView

            let circ = GMSCircle.init(position: marker.position, radius: 50)
            circ.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
            circ.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            circ.strokeWidth = 1
            circ.map = self.mapView
            //self.viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(coordinate, zoom: 14.0)
        }
    })
    self.overlay = AlertView.init(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
}
 func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if address == ""
    {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }

    else if let lookupAddress = address {
        var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
        geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

        let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)


            //let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>


            // Get the response status.
            let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

            if status == "OK" {
                let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                // Keep the most important values.
                self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
                let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
            }
            else {
                completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
            }

        })
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }
}
```

[image]